# Facebook App last seen user

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to know if a user is using my Facebook app in this moment? I tried to browse the Facebook Api Docs but is not very documented.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to track with last photo uploaded, last like, last comment, last post in time line etc. Which seems available in Facebook API.

Not that easy but acceptable.